# Very huge data avoid analytical function

Tags: sql, oracle, bigdata

Assume there are 100 million distinct SID values in this table.

Example: Table `test`, columns `SID, date_operation, score`

So in this table, score changes everyday so if I want to get report of all the SID with most recent score. Don't want to use analytical function as otherwise cost would be very high. Tried self join also but looks like that is also costly.

If this question is redundant please direct me to similar question I will delete it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Hooman Let me give example. Suppose table has only 4 records 
SID = 1 , date = 01-01-2018 score = 10 
SID = 2 , date = 01-01-2018 score = 20 
SID = 1 , date = 02-01-2018 score = 15 
SID = 2 , date = 02-01-2018 score = 100


The output should be : SID 1 = 15 and SID 2 = 100

Answer (score 1):

```
select sid, max(date_operation)
from test
group by sid
```

will return what you asked for:

> get all the Sid with most recent score

Comment: Nope, @Hooman. "most recent" to me means "MAX date", not "MAX score".

Comment: @Littlefoot but the OP wants the most recent score, so your query would need an extra column of `max(score) keep (dense_rank first order by date_operation desc)` to return the most recent score (and if there are more than one score for the most reecent date, the highest score).

Comment: Well, that's what you understood, @Boneist :), but the OP wrote that they need "SID with most recent score" - not "most recent score" but "SID ...". Probably Hooman's comment is correct, that is is unclear what's being asked. Thank you for your comment, though, you're absolutely right if *that* is what they, actually, need.

Comment: Agreed, the OP has been very ambiguous! Perhaps they want all SIDs with a score that matches the most recent. Who knows?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Apologies for not responding till now and apologies for ambiguous question...
Basically in a problem this is one of table which is joined to another table which has SID and another dimension of SID so what I wanted output from table test is 
SID value and its most recent score ... So output should have all SIDs and their most recent score ....

This is very easy but I am struggling with speed/performance  of getting output

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from test t2 where t2.sid = t.sid);
```

This can take advantage of an index on `test(sid, date)`.

However I have found good performance in Oracle with `keep`:

```
select sid, max(date),
       max(score) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc) as most_recent_score
from test
group by sid;
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why keep has better performance ?
Or any documentation to confirm before using this logic in production ?

Comment: @Svarmit . . . You should try out the two versions to see which is better.  I assume `keep` has good performance because Oracle has put the effort into optimizing it.